# What does this monad transformer type mean?

Tags: haskell, monads

Look at this thing from the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html#g:4):

```
type ErrorAndStateWithIO e s a = ErrorT e (StateT s IO) a
==> ErrorT (StateT s IO (Either e a))
==> ErrorT (StateT (s -> IO (Either e a,s)))
```

I attach also constructor of `ErrorT`:

```
Constructors
  ErrorT 
    runErrorT :: m (Either e a)
```

The thing that I can't understand is a thing on the top of my post. What does it mean? For me it means that `ErrorT e (StateT s IO) a = ErrorT (StateT s IO (Either e a))`. What's up? It is something like auto call constructor (`runErrorT`)?

The second thing that bothers me: We know form of `StateT` as `StateT s m a`. Here, we have `StateT s IO`. Where is `a` parameter?

And last thing - can somebody explain how to run this monad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the documentation is playing fast and loose with notation. They're replacing the types `ErrorT` and `StateT` with their constructors, which also have the names `ErrorT` and `StateT`. (It makes some sort of sense because they're `newtype`s.) The point the author is trying to make is that `ErrorAndStateWithIO e s a` is equivalent to `s -> IO (Either e a, s)`; it just has a couple of `newtype` wrappers around it.

Looking at the definitions of those types,

```
newtype ErrorT e m a = ErrorT { runErrorT :: m (Either e a) }
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }
```

you can see that in the first step the outer `ErrorT` has been replaced with its definition, and in the second the inner `StateT` has been replaced with its definition.

---

> Here, we have `StateT s IO`. Where is `a` parameter?

`ErrorT e` is a [monad transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html), which means it transforms monads into other monads. Monads always have a kind of `* -> *`; monad transformers have a kind of `(* -> *) -> (* -> *)`. `StateT s` is also a monad transformer. Here, `StateT s` is being applied to `IO` to produce a new monad (which is `IO` augmented with state-management capabilities), and then `ErrorT e` is being applied to that to produce another monad (which is `StateT s IO` augmented with error-handling capabilities).

---

> Can somebody explain how to run this monad?

As I mentioned above, `ErrorAndStateWithIO e s a` is just `s -> IO (Either e a, s)` with a couple of `newtype` wrappers around it. So to run it you'd unwrap the `newtype`s, pass in an `s`, plumb it into an IO computation and scrutinise the result.

```
myComputation :: ErrorAndStateWithIO String Int Char
myComputation =  -- ...

main = do
    (result, _) <- runStateT (runErrorT myComputation) 5
    case result of
         Left err -> putStrLn err
         Right result -> putStrLn $ "Success: " ++ [result]
```

Comment: When we use newtype then it may has only one constructor. Is it true that type is equivalent to constructor ? Additionally, where is the parameter `a` ?

Comment: A `newtype` is a wrapper around the type inside its constructor. It's isomorphic to that type; indeed, they are represented in the same way at runtime. The parameter `a` has been curried out to give a type of kind `* -> *`.